# Call to undefined function wp_generate_attachment_metadata()

Tags: images, attachments, pdf

In content-attachment.php I have:

```
/* preview for PDFs*/
if ('' === $ai) {
  wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $the_ID, wp_upload_dir() );
}
```

And it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() in /home/content/xx/html/example/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/post/content-attachment.php on line 110
```

Per another question here, I tried adding the following to the top of this file:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
```

And that generates a slew of errors like this:

```
Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/content/55/8933555/html/seatacnoise/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2797
```

Now what?

Answer (score 5):

Despite you already solved it (the "undefined" issue), it should be noted that [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) is defined in `wp-admin/includes/image.php`, so you need to manually load that file if you're using the function on the front-end, i.e. public side of the site or non admin/`wp-admin` pages (e.g. single attachment pages).

And in fact, the function reference says that:

> If this function is undefined in the environment where it is to be
> used, such as within a Shortcode, use the include function:
>
> ```
> if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_crop_image' ) ) {
>   include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
> }
> ```

(You may use `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` instead of that `wp_crop_image`)

Secondly, you're not properly using the function:

```php
wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $the_ID, wp_upload_dir() );
```

Because the second parameter for `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` should be the attachment *file path*, and not an array (`wp_upload_dir()` returns an array) or anything else. So for example:

```php
$file = '/full/path/to/the/attachment/file.pdf';
wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $the_ID, $file );
```

And make sure the file path is valid and that the `$the_ID` has the correct attachment post ID.

Comment: Did not work. Same error. Thanks.

Comment: Then, can you show more of your code or the new one that you tried? Are you sure `$the_ID` has the correct attachment post ID?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to test. With your suggestion, the error has gone away but the preview image is not generating. This seems to be an issue with Wordpress... on some PDFs it simply will not generate the preview images. I load the PDF into Acrobat and resave and then it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: If it's just for some PDFs, then it's probably a limitation in your web server - you can try [debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), but you'd need to post another question for further assistance on that preview image creation issue (other than the "undefined" and `preg_match()` issues).

Comment: Will do. What happens is this: 
1. A particular PDF will not- generate a preview.
2. I open it in Acrobat and re-save it and re-upload it to web server.
3. Presto... the preview now works.

So there is obviously -something- in certain PDFs that the wordpress engine doesn't like.

Comment: In that case, then, yes, maybe. And if you could share that PDF (the one before you re-saved it), I'd be happy to help you confirm whether it's indeed a problem with WordPress itself.